# How to pull the data from HP ALM?

Tags: c#, hp-quality-center, alm

Currently i'm trying to pull the data from HP ALM by using c#. In TestSet1 we have 9 fields: 'Name' 'Type', 'Status', 'Planned Host Name','Exec Date','Responsible Tester', 'Time', 'Planned Exec Date', 'Iterations'.

From the above, i have retrieved first 5 fields successfully and anyone know how to retrieve remaining fields "Responsible Tester", "Time", "Planned Exec Date", "Iterations" from ALM..

for better understanding see my code here:
[Getting System.__ComObject instead of data while pulling data from HP ALM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24256718/getting-system-comobject-instead-of-data-while-pulling-data-from-hp-alm)

Can anyone help me please...?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get them using the `Field` property:

```
test.Field("TC_TESTER_NAME") // Responsible Tester
test.Field("TC_EXEC_TIME") // Time
test.Field("TC_PLAN_SCHEDULING_DATE") // Planned Exec Date
test.Field("TC_ITERATIONS") // Iterations
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257331/hp-quality-center-field-names) for how to get the field names like `TC_TESTER_NAME`. From the OTA Reference, Object TSTest:

```
Public Property Field( _
    ByVal FieldName As String _
) As Variant
```

Not having a C#-Environment, I cannot test your code. But this Ruby code works fine (QC11):

```
test_set_factory = test_set.TSTestFactory
test_list = test_set_factory.NewList("")
test = test_list.Item(1) # Get some test instance from the test set
puts "ID/Name: #{test.ID}/#{test.Name}"
puts "Responsible Tester: #{test.Field("TC_TESTER_NAME")}"
```

Output:

```
ID/Name: 85/[1]Test A
Responsible Tester: roland
```

Comment: Hi Ronald , Now it is showing error:                    'TDAPIOLELib.TSTest' does not contain a definition for 'Field' and no extension method 'Field' accepting a first argument of type 'TDAPIOLELib.TSTest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) E:\Models\ConnectionClass.cs 99 44 TechnoKey_ALM

Comment: I extended my answer. Since I do not have a C#-environment ready, I cannot reproduce your error. But the `Field` property is documented in the OTA reference, and it is working fine in my test, so it should be there...

Comment: Hi Roland, I did get the field names by using  string a6 = Convert.ToString(r1["RN_EXECUTION_TIME"]); this result comes from RUN. If I give like this string a66 = Convert.ToString(test["TC_EXECUTION_TIME"]); its showing error "cannot found field name". where can I find the field names in C#?

Comment: finally i got it Roland... Thanks for your help... :)