# How to find the Field names in Defects in HP ALM?

Tags: c#, hp-quality-center, alm

I'm retrieving fields from HP ALM. But here I trouble to get the field names.

```
 BugFactory bf = (BugFactory)qcc.BugFactory;
 List bugs = (List)bf.NewList(bf.Filter.Text); 

string b5 = Convert.ToString(bg["BG_PROJECT"]); 
string b6 = Convert.ToString(bg["BG_STATUS"]);
string b7 = Convert.ToString(bg["BG_TARGET_CYCLE"]);
```

First two are fine to get result and Last statement showing Invalid field name error.

Please tell me the correct way to get field names.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to this question:

[HP Quality Center field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257331/hp-quality-center-field-names/24368561#24368561)

It has some sample code that shows how to programmatically determine the fields given a factory object. You have the BugFactory object which is the perfect start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Filter of the factory, for example the next is for AuditRecord you can use the samewith BugFactory

```
AuditRecordFactory auditLog = this.ALMConnection.AuditRecordFactory as AuditRecordFactory;
var auditLogFilter = auditLog.Filter as ITDFilter;
//Get the field list
List fieldList= auditLogFilter.Fields;
```

**UPDATE:** I found a complete answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24368561/3915468
:)

@TheArtTrooper provide a good answer with the next method

```
private void ExploreFactoryFieldDefinitions(IBaseFactory factory)
    {
        List fields = factory.Fields;

        foreach (TDField field in fields)
        {
            FieldProperty field_property = (FieldProperty)field.Property;

            if (field_property.IsRequired)
            {
                Log(String.Format("User Label: {0}\n", field_property.UserLabel));
                Log(String.Format("User Column Type: {0}\n", field_property.UserColumnType));
                Log(String.Format("DB Column Name: {0}\n", field_property.DBColumnName));
                Log(String.Format("DB Column Type: {0}\n", field_property.DBColumnType));
                Log(String.Format("DB Table Name: {0}\n", field_property.DBTableName));
            }
        }
    }
```