# Uploading Requirements to HP ALM

Tags: python, com, win32com, hp-alm

Does anybody know the attributes in python `win32com` that I need to set in order to upload requirements? I've successfully connected to HP-ALM (HPQC) 12.5, but when I try to upload requirements, it tells me that the  attribute can't be blank.

The documentation is extremely sparse on COM, and python though, so I'm having a really hard time figuring out what attributes I'm even able to set.

**Edit 1 The error I'm getting**

> 'Exception occurred.' (0, None, 'Required field **Acceptance
>   Criteria** can not be empty or SPACE filled.'

**Solution: The issue with HP ALM was that there are custom fields that were required to be populated. I was able to uncheck the box requiring the field to be populated, which allowed me to upload requirements. But, I still wasn't ever able to identify what the field actually was supposed to be.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the documentation on the COM API of ALM is quite good. E.g. for the [Req](http://alm-help.saas.hp.com/en/12.50/api_refs/ota/topic8457.html) object.

To get all mandatory fields I think the easiest way is to create a requirement in the ALM-Client (Web-UI). It depends on the customization of your ALM installation.

For me, this code works to create a new requirement (it's in Ruby, but it doesn't really matter):

```
req_factory = @tdc.ReqFactory
req = req_factory.AddItem(parent_id)
req.Name = "Some requirement"
req["RQ_TYPE_ID"] = "Functional"
req.Post
```

There also is a SO question on how to get [HP Quality Center field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257331/hp-quality-center-field-names/24261700#24261700)
.

Comment: The only thing I'm doing different from you is I'm not adding the parent_id directly. What datatype is the parent_id for you? I have a function that gets the parent_id. I'm starting to wonder if we have a custom requirement in our HPQC database that the acceptance criteria not be left blank.